# Title with big bold font

Tags: fonts, bold

I want the title `Fredholm Integral Transforms` to be displayed in large bold text.  With `\HUGE` I did not get a change in the font.

```latex
    \documentclass{book}
    
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{ paperheight=21cm, paperwidth=21cm, left=8mm, right=8mm,
      top=21mm, bottom=21mm}
    
    \usepackage{type1cm}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand\normalsize{%
       \@setfontsize\normalsize{13pt}{13pt}
       \abovedisplayskip 10\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus5\p@
       \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ \@plus3\p@
       \belowdisplayshortskip 6\p@ \@plus3\p@ \@minus3\p@
       \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
       \let\@listi\@listI}
    \makeatother
    
    \begin{document}
    \normalsize
    
    \begin{titlepage}
      \begin{flushleft}
        {\HUGE Fredholm Integral Transforms}
      \end{flushleft}
      \noindent\rule{19cm}{3pt}
    
      \vspace*{\fill}
      \date{\today}
      \begin{flushleft}
       An Author
       \noindent\rule{19cm}{1pt}
      \end{flushleft}
      
    \end{titlepage}
    
    %\maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Fourier Transform}
    
    \begin{equation} \label{eqn}
      f(\omega) = \int e^{ - i \omega t } f(t)  dt
    \end{equation}
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: `\HUGE` isn't defined. I guess you mean `\Huge`. BTW: `\@setfontsize\normalsize{13pt}{13pt}` are you *really* sure about that?

Comment: Might be an idea to replace `type1cm` by `fix-cm`, the latter allows fontsizes at any size (instead of quantized sizes), the former has not need needed for many many years

Comment: @daleif Actually `type1cm` also allows any size. But you are of course right that `fix-cm` supersedes `type1cm`.

Comment: @campa given that it hasn't been updated for 20 years....

Comment: Have checked `fix-cm` out.  Worked well.

Comment: I am not sure of `\@setfontsize\normalsize{13pt}{13pt}`.  Any introspection on that @campa?

Comment: 13pt font size with 13pt baseline distance looks very tight to me.

Comment: I require explanation on the term tight.  What do the two sizes refer to exactly?